# Can you include a second variable and increment and iterate that value in conjunction with another in a for loop? This is so that I can get indexes

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop

```
#include "helpers.h"
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

// Detect edges
void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    double sqrt(double x);
    int gx[9] = {-1, 0, 1, -2, 0, 2, -1, 0, 1};
  // int gx[3][3] = {{-1, 0, 1}, {-2, 0, 2}, {-1, 0, 1}};
  //gy array used to calculate the intesnity of the difference in colour in pixel
    int gy[9] = {-1, -2, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1};
  // int gy[3][3] = {{-1, -2, -1}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 1}};
  //RGBTRIPLE struct holds red, blue and green values
    RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];
    int pixelnum;
    int pixle1;
    int pixle2;
    int pixle3;
    int pixle11;
    int pixle22;
    int pixle33;

  //copy original image to copy
            for(int f = 0; f < height; f++){
                for(int b = 0; b < width; b++){
                //copy whole image as to get original values to use when calculating for the image output
                copy[f][b] = image[f][b];
            }
        }

  //go through each pixel at i's row and j's column
            for(int i = 0; i < height; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < width; j++){
                    pixle1 = pixle2 = pixle3 = 0;
                    pixelnum = 0.0;
                    pixle11 = pixle22 = pixle33 = 0;

  //make boundaries surrounding the original pixel to iterate through
for(int x = i - 1; x <= i + 1; x++){

    for(int y = j - 1; y <= j + 1; y++){

  //if the surrounidng pixel's of [i][j] are out of bounds, value set to 0(black)
if(x < 0  || x > height - 1 || y < 0 || y > width - 1){

    pixelnum ++;
        continue;
            }else if(x >= 0 && x <= height - 1 && y >= 0 && y <= width - 1){
  //if position is within the image
  //use both the gx and gy matrix by calculating gx(position of surrounidng pixel value) =+
  //same for gy matrix
        pixelnum ++;
        pixle1 = pixle1 + (gx[pixelnum - 1] * copy[x][y].rgbtRed);
        pixle2 = pixle2 + (gx[pixelnum - 1] * copy[x][y].rgbtGreen);
        pixle3 = pixle3 + (gx[pixelnum - 1] * copy[x][y].rgbtBlue);


        pixle11 = pixle11 + (gy[pixelnum - 1] * copy[x][y].rgbtRed);
        pixle22 = pixle22 + (gy[pixelnum - 1] * copy[x][y].rgbtGreen);
        pixle33 = pixle33 + (gy[pixelnum - 1] * copy[x][y].rgbtBlue);

      }
}

                }
  //square the calculated value then do the same to the other calulating value (gx squared + gy squared) then round it to an int
    int red = round(sqrt(pixle1 * pixle1 + pixle11 * pixle11));
    int green = round(sqrt(pixle2 * pixle2 + pixle22 * pixle22));
    int blue = round(sqrt(pixle3 * pixle3 + pixle33 * pixle33));
                        // Cap at 255
    if (red > 255)
    {
        red = 255;
    }
    if (green > 255)
    {
        green = 255;
    }
    if (blue > 255)
    {
        blue = 255;
    }
  //put new value in image array
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = red;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = green;
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = blue;

         }
    }
       return;
}
```

The program works as intended, it creates an edge filter. However I did not do it exactly how I was meant to. I should have used a 2d array for gx and gy but I did not know how to increment and iterate over the array in conjunction to the x and y loop. Both gx and gy need to be in the same position as the x and y loop which I could not figure out. This is because the x and y loop don't include values outside it's bounds but for a gx/gy 2d array it would need to include it in its incrementation to have the same position as x and y. I thought maybe I could increment/iterate gx/gy 2d array using an extra variable index value in x and y for loops. But I could not find how

Comment: Why all this code to demonstrate what you are asking about? The answer is _yes_. `for(int i=0, j=0; condition; ++i, ++j)`. Also, please indent your code properly.

Comment: Will `pixelnum` never be above `9`?

Comment: Aside: it's a bad habit to do `x > height - 1`, instead do `x >= height`. It's easier to read, and your way can be error-prone when working with `unsigned` types.

Comment: Why the `else if(<opposite to the condition already tested>)`? Just test if the location is on the image and remove all the other nonsense.

Comment: When I tried that "for(int i=0, j=0; condition || condition; ++i, ++j)" it did not work? I need to incorporate the two variables for two different 2d arrays that have different bounds but start the same"0"

Comment: Try `conditionA && conditionB`.

Comment: Some programmer dude - it will never be above 9 because it essentially counts around and through one pixel each time in the image.

Comment: Weather Vane - thank you for your advice, I will take a second look at this area in my code, as I know it is important for the code to be readable.

Comment: Weather Vane - thank you for your comment. I don't think this would work because if the condition is false in one of the two conditions then it will not increment? since they will have different bounds, they won't always both be true

Comment: It isn't clear what you are attempting. What I put, it to end the loop when either condition is false, so they both must be true to continue. Why would you want to continue if one of the contitions is false?

Comment: Are you *sure*? Have you tried to print out the values? It's not that I don't trust you, but the code is so complicated and the indentation so messed up it's impossible to follow. And since it's not a [mre] it's impossible for me to check myself. Also, if you increase it *after* you use it then you should not have to use `pixelnum - 1` as indexes. And since `pixelnum` is an `int` why assign the `double` value `0.0` to it?

Comment: lots of `for` loops here, not sure which one you're talking about. But if you're at a pixel, and trying to visit all the pixels neighbors, you're going to need nested loops, unless there's some clever way to do it in one that I'm not thinking about (not counting loop unrolling). See [this](https://godbolt.org/z/GxGKW6rY6)

Comment: Thank you, I will try that method and see if it works  @Weather Vane

Comment: I will print out the values again to see, I have not looked back at this code for some time but I think it is set to 0.0 because in the calculation the answer carries a decimal number for accuracy's sake and then is rounded to the nearest whole number.

Comment: Im talking about the 5th and 6th for loops. There is 2 2d arrays I wanted to iterate at the same time using different conditions at the same time. I was not able to find a solution so I made gx/gy into a normal array but the assignment was to use a 2d array instead @yano